# Passing data/variable from a Visual Basic form to a Flash Object

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3, flash, visual-studio-2013

I'm pretty sure that this can be answered somewhere here on stackOverflow but I'm out of options with this.

I have a VisualBasic form with an button object on it. I would like that button to have an onClick procedure so that clicking it passes a variable or other command to another window which has a Shockwave Flash "movie" running. (For example, there is a function on the ActionScript of the Flash file to display some text in the Flash Video running when invoked.)

What am I missing to make this possible? I know it's something about the `fscommand` but not sure how to pass a variable from VB with it.

Comment: http://nitin-sinha.blogspot.ca/2009/07/visual-basic-and-as30-communication.html

Comment: Both responses are useful but would you care to form it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is using the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class in AS3.  It allows data to be passed between AS3 and the host application/container (be that a webpage or a VB Form etc).

In the AS3 side, you set it up as follows:

```
function myAS3Function(someNumber:Number, someObject:Object)
{
    //do something with your number and object
    trace(someObject.isAwesome);

    return "hello from AS3";
}

//register your function with a label VB can call/invoke
if (ExternalInterface.available){
   ExternalInterface.addCallback("myAS3Function", myAS3Function);
}
```

From the host side, you [send/recieve XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7caf) to the ActiveX object.

Your XML looks like this:

```
<invoke name="myAS3Function" returntype="xml">
    <arguments>
        <number>5</number>
        <object>
            <property id="foo"><string>bar</string></property>
            <property id="isAwesome"><true/></property>
        </object>
    </arguments>
</invoke>
```

---

Now, construct that XML in VB, and invoke the `CallFunction` method of the VB flash object, passing it the xml string.

```
Dim returnValue As String
returnValue = MyFlashShockWaveObj.CallFunction(xml)

MsgBox(returnValue) 'hello from flash
```

If you are passing a lot of objects, sometimes it easiest to just JSON.stringify them and pass just one JSON string over to AS3 (and/or back).

Comment: Just to ask, this will still work with VS2013 and VS2015 right? Is there anything special that I need to do with the .FLA/.SWF file to import it into VS?

Comment: This is a part of the ShockwaveFlash ActiveX component, regardless of language or IDE.   I've used it before in C# with VS2013 - though I haven't done any VB work in about a decade or dove into VS2015 yet.

Comment: Can I ask another question? Would this change if instead of a SWF flash object I use Adobe AIR or is that another best altogether?

Comment: Yes it would change,  AIR relies on methods build into it's executable wrapper that you don't get with the ActiveX component.  There are ways however to communicate from application to application if you had an AIR app running side by side with a VB app.

Comment: Would you happen to have any of the documentation for this? Or know of a link to a guide about such?

Comment: There's a few ways you go about it,  sockets, native extension, native processes.  Here are some links to help get you started:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html        

http://www.leebrimelow.com/new-two-part-tutorial-on-air-2-0-nativeprocess/