# Integrating VB.NET with Flash in Visual Studio 2015 (Community)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently in the middle of making a VB.NET project. I want to have the VB.NET project control the actions of the Flash projector. (Stop, play, change text of text control in the Flash projector, etc.) This is a one way control however, nothing about the SWF projector will interact back with the VB.NET project.

The image below shows an idea of what I want to have done.

[image: Ideal goal of application]

EDIT: Okay I managed to get a SWF object available to be put in the project. So now, my question is how do I get the two (Visual Studio and the SWF object that is being included in another form windows) to interact. That is, if I push a button on VisualBasic, I can call a function in AS3/SWF to do something and receive a variable from the Visual Basic form.

The AS3 code contains the following

```
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    lblText.text = "Congrats! It Works!";
}

btnChange.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);
```

Here is a photo of the actual SWF.

[image: Mock SWF]

What I would like to do is invoke this function (or some similar function) passing info to the SWF projector (being run as an ActiveX Flash object in Visual Studio) from the VB form. (Ignore the button on the actual SWF, that button won't be there on the final run) I'm running into two problems:

1) How do I modify `addEventListener` so that it can take more than one parameter or is there another event or function I could use?

2) How do I invoke this function from within Visual Studio as a part of a sub or function from within VS/VB.NET?

I don't need it to reciprocate, as in Visual Studio getting information from the SWF.

Comment: To communicate between your VB.NET app and the swf, you can use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), for that, take a look on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31751792/2256820) where you can find a simple example.

Comment: That's actually my question from a while ago.... I just didn't remember I posted it. But this sounds like it's going from SWF to VB. Is it the other way around?

Comment: I didn't even see that was yours ;) No, it's VB who is calling an ActionScript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran a quick test using sendkeys and it worked ok; at the heart of it was:

setting the flashplayer as the foreground window ...

> Friend Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd
>   As IntPtr) As Integer

and then using the sendkeyes command

> System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait

Comment: Was hoping to not use the `SendKeys` method but `ExternalInterface`. However especially since I'm trying to send entire strings of data over to the Flash SWF.

Comment: I more or less took this from a freeware program I wrote, you should be able to send very long strings of data without a problem.  In a test of my program, A Form Filler, it flawlessly typed Act 1 Scene 1 of Hamlet into Microsoft Notepad at just over 300 words per minute - so hopefully you should be ok :-)

Comment: Hmm. I might have to attempt this method then... because writing XML isn't exactly fun. Do you happen to know wher eI can see the full source then?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out socket connections. They are easy to do with C++ and Flash has built in support for them:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html