# How can I embed an swf in a vb form without loosing functionality?

Tags: php, sql, vb.net, actionscript-3, flash

I have an swf which I want to embed in a vb form.
the swf is on a url like http://siteurl.com/subdir/file.swf
my problem is when I embed the swf in the form it does not allow for communication with sql through php.

I made a very lenient crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>

<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>

<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
```

and set the flash local playback security under the publish settings to 
access network only.
but still no luck.
Is what Im trying to do possible?, or am I going the wrong rout with this?

also I know the crossdomain.xml is very poorly setup, just trying everything to see if I can get it working at all really haha.

PS:
I have had a couple badly received questions, not sure why. but if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: do you include ` <--param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> where you embed swf..  share how you embed swf and your interacting codes,even browser logs

Comment: I embed the swf in a vb application, how should I use that line in the vb application? also I embed the application with the shockwave flash object and simply set the movie to the url in the properties panel. also I am not using a browser I am using the vb application, how could I check the logs?  also the swf doesn't really have any code that interacts with the vb client, should it?

Comment: i notice "in vb application" now. i commented over a html page i have no experience with swf in vb app. sorry for time but as an advice, use try catch on both sides. you can not know what is not working without knowing what is working and share as3 codes and vb codes to get more help. of course swf must have interaction codes take a look these as getting started steps http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Tutorials/Amethyst-Tutorials/article/how-to-add-swfs-to-net.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736018/passing-data-variable-from-a-visual-basic-form-to-a-flash-object

Comment: ok thank you Ill give it a look